# How to redirect two above?

Tags: php, html, path

I have a PHP page that has a form in it. I want to pass the values to a PHP page that is in another folder which is two folder above. The directories are:

`public\hse\forklift.php`

```
private\hse\forklift_form.php
```

And here is the code:

```
     <form method="post" action="../../private/forklift_form.php">

        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save">
        <input type="reset" name="sub" value="Clear">

    </form>
```

Comment: try putting the whole URL in form action, like `http://localhost/yourproject/private/forklift_form.php`...

Comment: Seems above code is correct, check the spell.

Comment: @LokiSinclair that was just an ex, the basic Idea was to define a `root URL` of the project, so the form action will be  `$root_url.private/forklift_form.php`

Comment: do u think it has with iis configuration? coze i binded http to the public folder and trying to access the private folder